# Number of ways different sizes boxes, “Moham numbers”?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Suppose you have $n$ indistinguishable objects and $k$ boxes with sizes $1,2,\ldots,k$. What is the number of ways you can put the objects in the boxes?

I read about this in a series of numbers call something like "Moham numbers", but I could not find it again. Does anyone know about the real name of this kind of numbers?

Comment: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/106161/36614) is a relevant answer on MathOverflow. In the case where no box can be left empty, you get "limited compositions." I could not find one for your specific setup though.